# Command line application to run the process in job

Tags: windows, process, jobs

Is there any? I could find only how to run the tasks in windows scheduler. No utility to run it as job, i.e. via CreateJobObject() - AssignProcessToJobObject(). 
I need my application killed if it consumes > 1.5 Gb RAM, job would be perfect to do that...

Comment: `winrs` and `winrm` seem to do what you want. See [Quota Management for Remote Shells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309367). The following command sets the memory quota to 1536MB (1.5GB): `winrm set winrm/config/winrs @{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="1536"}`. Run a command using `winrs [command]`. Enumerate running shells using `winrm enumerate shell`. Kill a job tree by deleting the shell: `winrm delete shell?ShellId=[Shell_GUID]`.

Comment: `accesschk -qost job` confirms that each shell gets a named job object, where the name is of the form `Winrs_Shell_JOB_GUID`. However, it's not the same GUID as the `ShellId`. I called `OpenJobObject` with the job name and then `QueryInformationJobObject` to get the `JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION`. This confirmed that the job was configured to use the `MaxMemoryPerShellMB` and `MaxProcessesPerShell` from the winrm configuration.